# JQuery Execute Json Data using KeyPress

Tags: jquery, json, keypress

i have some problem,

I create searchbox which consuming data from JSON array. This searchbox is working properly if user click the button, but when pressed enter, the function is not working.

Here's the click button syntax

```
   $("#btnsearch").click(function() {
        $("#divContent").hide("slow");
        $("#posting").html("");
        //show the div section
        $("#divContent").show("slow", function(){
            $("#divPage").hide("slow");       
            //getting value from searchbox
            valobj = $('#search_box').val();
            if(valobj == ""){
                $("#posting").append("Please Insert Keyword to Search!");
            } else {
            //execute data from database.
            $.getJSON("stitle.php", { title : valobj }, function(data,result){
                //show result from database
                if(data.content == ""){
                    $("#posting").append("Sorry, your search result is not found!");
                } else {
                    $.each(data.content, function(index, value) {
                        var li = $("<li><h3></h3><p></p></li>");
                        $("#posting").append(li);
                        $("h3",li).html("<a href='post.php?id="+ value.id +"'>" + value.title + "</a>");
                        $("p",li).text(value.intro_text);           
                    });

                    $(function(){
                        $("div.holder").jPages({
                            containerID : "posting",
                            perPage: 5
                        });
                        $(".holder").show();
                    });
                }   //end if 
            }, 'JSON'); //end show result
          } // show result if keyword is present 
        }); //end show div section
        $("#leftregion").hide();
        $("#rightregion").hide();
    }); //end click function
```

I want to create this method executed if user press enter key. I have read that, jquery need to use keypressed method.

```
    $(document).on("keypress", "#search_box", function(e) {
        var valobj = this.value;
        if(e.which == 13){
            $("#divContent").show("slow");
            $("#posting").html("");   
             if(valobj == ""){
                $("#posting").append("Please Insert Keyword to Search!");
            } else {
                //do the same function like code above 
                $.getJSON("stitle.php", { title : valobj }, function(data.......
            }
        }
    });
```

But the method is not working, any suggestion?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

i'm change the code into this

```
 $("#search_box").keypress(function(e) {
        valobj = $('#search_box').val();
        if(e.which == 13){
            $("#divContent").show("slow",function(){
            $("#posting").html("");   
            if(valobj == ""){
                $("#posting").append("Please Insert Keyword to Search!");
            } else {
                //do the same function like code above 
               $.getJSON("stitle.php", { title : valobj }, function(data,result){

                   $.each(data.content, function(index, value) {
                        var li = $("<li><h3></h3><p></p></li>");
                        $("#posting").append(li);
                        $("h3",li).html("<a href='post.php?id="+ value.id +"'>" + value.title + "</a>");
                        $("p",li).text(value.intro_text);           
                    });

                    $(function(){
                        $("div.holder").jPages({
                            containerID : "posting",
                            perPage: 5
                        });
                        $(".holder").show();
                    });
               }, 'JSON'); //end get JSON function
            }
         }); //end show function
       }
    });
```

but it's not working. Am i missing something? any suggestion?

thank you.

Comment: instead of binding your action to the button click, why not bind to the form's onsubmit?

Comment: how to do that @nderscore? can you give some example in the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function would look like the below. So within your document ready event you would use .on() to bind the keypress event handler to the search_box:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $(document).on("keypress", "#search_box", function(e) {
        valobj = $('#search_box').val();
        if(e.which == 13){
            $("#divContent").show("slow",function(){
            $("#posting").html("");   
            if(valobj == ""){
                $("#posting").append("Please Insert Keyword to Search!");
            } else {
                //do the same function like code above 
               $.getJSON("stitle.php", { title : valobj }, function(data,result){

                   $.each(data.content, function(index, value) {
                        var li = $("<li><h3></h3><p></p></li>");
                        $("#posting").append(li);
                        $("h3",li).html("<a href='post.php?id="+ value.id +"'>" + value.title + "</a>");
                        $("p",li).text(value.intro_text);           
                    });

                    $(function(){
                        $("div.holder").jPages({
                            containerID : "posting",
                            perPage: 5
                        });
                        $(".holder").show();
                    });
               }, 'JSON'); //end get JSON function
            }
         }); //end show function
       }
    });

})
```

EDIT: updated answer as per the discussion below.

Comment: This seems wrong if the page could have multiple input fields. They shouldn't all trigger the search function.

Comment: You could run an additional check to see which input box is populated and do something based on that.

Comment: You could, but why not just bind it to the element you care about in the first place? What does this method gain? And isn't that essentially how `$(document).on("keypress", "#search_box", function...)` works?

Comment: You could be right, I always thought that doing $(document).on("keypress", "#search_box", function...) requires search_box to have the focus for the event to trigger. Let me set up a fiddle to test.

Comment: Of course it does, but isn't that expected? If it doesn't have the focus, then you're not pressing Enter in that field.

Comment: @JanR the document is defined in the javascript $(document).ready(function () { any suggestion? please see my updated section. thanks

Comment: Have you tried Barmar's suggestion changing the $('#search_box').keypress to $(document).on("keypress", "#search_box", function...)?

Comment: @JanR i have try both inside and outside the script, but it reacts nothing.

Comment: change $(document).keypress(function(e) { to  $(document).on("keypress", "#search_box", function(e) {

Comment: @JanR i have updated the code to $(document).on("keypress", "#search_box", function(e) {  from  $("#search_box").keypress(function(e) { as updated 2.

Comment: any chance I can see the site to test?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32048/discussion-between-randytan-and-janr)